Two different projects sharing secret.json locally
I have a few different git projects in Azure DevOps, some of them forked another one.
When I change something in the secret of one it is replicated in the other one as well. I don't know if it happens with other files, I have only been able to detect it in this secret.json.
I have tried to download these projects again, but the problem remains.
Can a file point to a repository that the solution itself does not point to? Where is the secret.json file or where is defined to be generated? I can't find it.
If I download one of these projects along with a non-problematic one, the latter also starts sharing the secret.json.
When we deploy several of these projects to the Staging server (some web app, others workers as backgroundservice), will they also be affected?
I have found this in that projects share this line. Is it the issue? How do I rectify this?
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-XXXXXXXXXXXService-XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX</UserSecretsId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

@Ziyang Liu-MSFT
1 - When you add a character, that same character appears in the other secret.json
2 - Yes, an Azure git repo.
3 - No, only are shared with a problematics.
4 - As we always do, cloning the repository to our location. git clone command


Please clarify "When I change something in the secret of one it is replicated in the other one as well." in detail.  2. Is the "project" you are talking about an Azure git repo? 3. "If I download one of these projects along with a non-problematic one, the latter also starts sharing the secret.json." - How do you download the project? What it means "the latter also starts sharing the secret.json"?


@ZiyangLiu-MSFT Many thanks for helping here. Correction done. Many thanks again

I can't reproduce the issue from my side. To make it clearer, please help clarify these: 1. "When I change something in the secret of one" - How do you change it? Change it from UI or locally? 2. "it is replicated in the other one as well"  -When you say "the other one", do you mean another Azure repo on the UI or another local repo cloned from the same Azure repo? 3. Try to make some changes to other files and check if there is the same issue.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT -  It is when I add any type of character to one of the secrets from a local repository, the change is replicated to the other local repository. The problem does not occur in other files. Thank you very much again for your help.

Thanks for your update. To narrow down the issue, please help confirm and try these: 1. Can you help confirm that the other local repos and the local repo where you made changes are cloned from the same Azure repo? 2. Have you run git push after changing your secret.json file? 3. Is there a .gitignore file in your repo? 4. Is there the same issue if you create a brand-new repo in Azure DevOps? (Don't fork repo)

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT - No, the two local repositories were cloned from 2 different repositories, both forked from an initial one. No, just by saving the secret file, it is synchronized with the other secret file. Yes, there is a gitignore in the repository, but it does not include json files. If I create a new brand, there is no problem. From what I have seen, the problem seems to come from the  of the .csproj

Hi @Kenzo_Gilead, it's the expected behavior. Your projects are linked to one user secret file, which is stored on your local development machine. So that when you change it in one project, your other projects will also see the latest version. See my answer below for details.

The UserSecretsId is used to link the project to a set of user secrets stored on the development machine. This is part of the Secret Manager tool, which helps keep sensitive data like connection strings, API keys, and other secrets out of your source code.
When you right-click your project in Visual Studio and select “Manage User Secrets,” a UserSecretsId element is added to your project file. The file is placed beneath C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<id> where <username> matches your Windows user and <id> is a randomly generated GUID. The important thing to notice here is that the file is located outside your project directory. See more info about UserSecretsId from ASP.NET Core (not that secret) User Secrets Explained.
